# update database with checkboxes - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

So I have a users model which is associated to activities and activities are associated to a completed model?.

What I am trying to do is update if an activity is completed when a checkbox is clicked.

Here is my view:

```
  <% @user.completeds.each do |task| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= task.activity.name %></td>
      <td><%= task.activity.type.name %></td>
      <td><%= task.activity.points %></td>

      <td><%= check_box_tag 'finished', '1', task.finished %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

This all works great and shows if an activity is "finished" but I am having a hard time figuring out how to update the database with the checkbox. While I would like it to update when you click the checkbox I am ok with having a save button to save them all at once. Which ever would be easier probably would be best for me as I am just learning rails.

Thank you for any help.

**Edit:**

To clarify my question, my code above works for showing the data correctly, what I can't figure out is how to turn it into a form so that I can save any changes to the check box values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use a form and a save button. If you look at the [Form Helpers Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#helpers-for-generating-form-elements), you can see an example:

```
<%= check_box_tag(:pet_dog) %>
<%= label_tag(:pet_dog, "I own a dog") %>
```

You probably want to use form_for, not form_tag though to update your object. See the documentation [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper).

```
<%= form_for task do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :finished %>:
  <%= f.check_box :finished %><br />
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

EDIT:
To update multiples, try something like this:

```
<% form_tag edit_multiple_products_path do %>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <% @user.completeds.each do |task| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= task.activity.name %></td>
        <td><%= task.activity.type.name %></td>
        <td><%= task.activity.points %></td>
        <td><%= check_box_tag 'finished', '1', task.finished %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<%= submit_tag "Update Tasks" %>
<% end %>
```

Except don't forget to do everything else that the [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple) mentions.

Comment: Any way to do this with a single save/submit button?

Comment: Yup! Check out this example RailsCast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple

Comment: Basically, you still want a form like in my example, but you need a unique path to update multiples.

Comment: Ok this gets me close I think but I guess I was not very clear. I am just trying to update the "finished" value in the database to a 1 or 0 based on what is checked. Im not trying to update all the other columns.

Comment: The example code I posted would only update a single column.